# Converting a string to float using std::istringsteam in C++

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

I've been trying to convert a simple string to a float, but I'm having no luck with it. this is what I've got at the moment:

```
int main()
{
    float value;
    std::string stringNum = "0.5";
    std::istringstream(stringNum) >> value;

    return 0
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Error   2   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'std::istringstream'    c:\users\administrator\desktop\Test\main.cpp    12
```

can anyone give me some guidance here on how to just simply convert the string to a float?

Thanks

Comment: Shorter version would be `std::istringstream{std::string{"0.5"}} >> value ;`

Comment: @0x499602D2: Even shorter: `std::istringstream{"0.5"} >> value;`

Comment: @AndyProwl lol that too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you haven't included all the relevant headers:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=322c5fd55c0dc899b0ab7b18f905aad3-0bcbabce5e03da787bd7f789f9dd7c18) showing that your code compiles when the appropriate headers are included.

In general, you should not rely on indirect inclusion of a necessary standard header file from another standard header file (unless, of course, this inclusion is documented in the Standard itself).

Also notice, that you are creating a *temporary* string stream, which will be destroyed at then end of the evaluation of the expression

```
std::istringstream(stringNum) >> value
```

You may want to create a stream object this way instead:

```
std::istringstream ss(stringNum);
ss >> value;

// Here you can use ss again...
```